# Using columnrange chart type in Highcharts with custom output?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts library with Angular 4. I want to create a chart something like below:

[image]

For the above chart I am using columnrange type chart. Below is the link what I have tried for this:

[https://jsfiddle.net/w1jwd1oz/](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/w1jwd1oz/)

How to clear the gap between the bars so that is looks like same as in screen shot?

Comment: In the screen shot GHRM,DEA,MBM,HR Scanner,Qualtrics are applications name and In x-Axis we are showing the release dates of the applications

Comment: Please let me know If it can be achieved by using any other type of chart in highcharts

Comment: Below is the working URL:https://jsfiddle.net/w1jwd1oz/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this answers what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/w1jwd1oz/1/

You basically need to define a height of 240px to achieve what you want otherwise it will use a default height.

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 240px; min-width: 310px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks PKA, this  is working  if height is 240px. I am curious to know, Is there any other property for this type of requirement.I have tried "groupPadding" property but it is not working. In my case chart height is more than 300px.

Comment: I am able to remove the white border between ranges by setting : borderWidth: 0 ,
shadow: false

Comment: No problem! not to my knowledge. Can you update the fiddle so I know what you're talking about?

Comment: No issue, I able to fix it by reducing by giving the fix height.

Comment: Thanks PKA, I am able to achieve the required result in my case with your suggested solution.Working URL :                                                                      http://jsfiddle.net/72dfgLvd/